# using extract.autodesk.io and automatically download bubbles to our local server

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to use and modify the extract.autodesk.io (thanks to Cyrille Fauvel) but not yet successful. In a nut shell, this is what I want to do:

1. user drag-drop the design file (i'm ok with this)
2. I've removed the submit button - so right after uploading, extraction should begin in autodesk's server. (i've added a .done to trigger the auto-extraction : uploadFile (uri).done(function(){SubmitProjectDirect();}); )
3. no need to load a temp viewer for view/test
4. automatically download the bubble in zip file into our local server folder.
5. Delete uploaded model right away as our projects are mostly strictly confidential.

I'm encountering a 405 'Method not allowed' on 'api/file' sub folder, which I believe it should be autodesk's folder in the server.
Can anyone point the root urn of api/file?

I seem to get stuck on item 2 above due to the 405 error. But if get passed that one, I still need to solve 3, 4 and 5.
Appreciate any help...

Comment: On which API endpoint do you get the 405 error? is it when calling the DELETE buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName (aka ObjectsApi.deleteObject() method) ? the forge team made a bugfix on this endpoint a week ago, make sure to update the Forge SDK to the latest version, and let me know.

Comment: Hi Cyrille. Thanks for your reply. The error is during the upload:  
'$(document).ready (function () {
 var r =new Flow ({
  target: '/api/file',
  chunkSize: 1024 * 1024,
  /*forceChunkSize: true,*/
  testChunks: false
 }) ;'  
- it seems that the file is being uploaded in our own local server's '/api/file' path, instead of autodesk's, i believe as the extraction process should happen in autodesk's server ?  
My objective is to automate your extract where the user only-dragdrop the file and our server should then transparently download and unzip the file and refresh the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of the additional comment above, the issue is a bit more complicated than I thought originally. In order to upload a file on the Autodesk cloud storage, you need to use specific endpoints, with a PUT verb and provide an oAuth Access Token.
It should be possible to setup the Flow.js to use all the above, but since it is a javascript library running on your client, it means anyone can steal your access token and use it illegitimately to either access your data, or consume your cloud credit to do action on your behalf. 
Another issue is that the OSS minimum chunk is 5Mb - see [this article](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/oss-resumable-upload-minimum-chunk-sizes.html), so you need to control this as well as providing OSS the byte assembly range information.
I would not recommend uploading to OSS from the client directly for security reason, but if you do not want to store on your server as a temporary storage, we can either proxy the Flow.js upload on the OSS storage or pipe the uploaded chunk on the Autodesk cloud storage. Both of the solution will be secured with no storage on your server, but traffic will continue to go via your server. I will create a branch on the [github repo](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) in a few days to demonstrate both approach.

Comment: Thanks, Cyrille! That's very kind of you.

Comment: @Efren Abella: Done in branch [streamupload](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/tree/streamupload). I briefly tested it and it is working fine on my side. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: @Efren Abella - does it work for you? any questions?

Comment: wow man! it's working! After obtaining my tokens and installing the dependencies, i was blown away...
I'm just trying to modify it now to transparently download the bubbles in my local server folder without the user's interaction...any suggestion where should i tweak that? 
Thanks so much...

Comment: @Efren Abella- if you goal is to do a web service vs a website, it would be easier to specify a new application to get rid of the UI. Anyway, to answer your question, you need to modify the code [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/streamupload/www/js/app.js#L206) and do an Ajax call similar to what is done [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/streamupload/views/explore.ejs#L341) I can help on both, but I would recommend you close this thread and accept it a a solution, and contact me @ autodesk.com, to specify the app as you want it to work

Comment: thanks again, Cyrille! will look into your suggestion. will close this thread as answered...